# correct type for a signature for a generic output class

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, iostream

I would just ask for a confirmation, in my opinion if I'm writing a `foo` function and I would like to give a flexible option about the object used for the output, I would use a `std::ostream&` type, like that, `void foo(std::ostream& stream, ... )` so the user of `foo` is able to pick anything from the `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, to a generic file output.

Could you confirm that this is a good choice ? My only doubt is about making this work cleanly even in the case when concurrent access is needed, but I think that the user always expects to manage the lock ( since I don't think I/O streams can possibly be atomic ) on his own before and after calling this function, so I don't really think that a function used for the output should contain elements of concurrent design inside its own definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, that sounds fine to me.**

I use it in my own code, even!

I would mostly agree that `foo` shouldn't lock, but it's hard to say so categorically without knowing more about the application. It sounds like you have a good grasp of the choice involved so I'll leave that part down to your judgement.